# Call another VBS routine from the script that is running

Tags: vbscript

I have a script that opens a file, performs a file > save as routine and closes the file.

I would like to run my save as routine, then part way through call a separate VBS script that will change my locale / region setting on the PC (this script is in another vbs file), then my script will continue and do the save as routine, and finally call another script that will reset my locale /region.

I could just paste the code into one big script, but in the interest of keeping it clean, my preference would be to call it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, anyway... You probably either want to change your timezone:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "tzutil.exe /s ""Hawaiian Standard Time""", 1, true
sh.Run "w32tm.exe /resync", 1, true
```

Or to change region/location :
[Change the system Region/Location setting using vbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779094/change-the-system-region-location-setting-using-vbs)

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686454/run-a-vbscript-from-another-vbscript).

```
Dim objShell: Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "set_timezone.vbs" 
'Complete the save routine...
objShell.Run "revert_timezone.vbs" 
Set objShell = Nothing
```